# Grails: how to upload location to localhost?

Tags: grails, upload, localhost

How to set Grails to upload the location localhost?

```
f = request.getFile('Filedata')
if(!f.empty) {
    f.transferTo( new File("http://localhost/uploads" + File.separatorChar + f.getOriginalFilename()))
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error:

> (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).
>   Stacktrace follows: Message: http:\localhost\uploads\images.jpg (The
>   filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

But when I specify "c:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/" it is working. What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If you save files inside the application directory they will be deleted when you re-deploy on the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to transfer a file like this. The filedata needs to be saved on a physical location to the filesystem. The error message clearly explains this. The "http://localhost" is not a filesystem but a local webhost. The "c:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/" is a real location so that works!

So you should save the file to the directory which is mounted to the

> `http://localhost/uploads`

mountpoint.